# How to return a file from an ajax action in Phoenix?

Tags: ajax, elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to return a file to a client from an action which is called via ajax. How can I do that? I've found this as an example:

```
conn
|> put_resp_content_type("text/csv")
|> put_resp_header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"something.txt\"")
|> send_resp(200, txt_file_content)
```

But it's applicable only for a normal request, not ajax. How can I adapt it for ajax?

Comment: Just `send_resp(conn, 200, txt_file_content)` should work if you want binary data back. If you want JSON, you can do `json(conn, %{contents: txt_file_content})`. How are you using the AJAX response in your JS code?

Comment: `How are you using the AJAX response in your JS code?` -- I'm not. How should I use it to allow a user receive a file via ajax, that is, what should be in `onSuccess` on a client?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Are you wanting them to be able to save the file onto their computer? Is this just to display the contents of the file? Is it always going to a text file, or could their be images?

Comment: @Dogbert `How are you using the AJAX response in your JS code?` -- I'm not. How should I use it to allow a user receive a file via ajax, that is, what should be in `onSuccess` on a client?